# how to create Meta-rules and/or meta-interpreter for an Expert System with Swi-Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-metainterpreter

I wanna create an expert system with meta-interpreter with SWI-Prolog... what is the best and the easier way to make it? which is the procedure to make it?

Comment: Take a look a this: [Amzi](http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/).   And [Clips](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) is not Prolog at all; but well worth looking at.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 3):

Many of the meta-interpreters for expert systems are based on the 
so called vanilla interpreter. This is an interpreter for
Prolog without cut and without built-ins. it reads as follows:

```
solve(true) :- !.
solve((A,B)) :- !, solve(A), solve(B).
solve(H) :- clause(H,B), solve(B).
```

You can readily use it to solve the following knowledge base
and query. In some Prolog systems, the more ISO compatible ones, you need to mark the predicates dynamic, so that clause/2 can find them:

```
pet(dog):- size(medium), noise(woof).
pet(cat):- size(medium), noise(meow).
pet(mouse):- size(small), noise(squeak).
size(medium).
noise(meow).

?- solve(pet(X)).
X=cat
```

Starting from the vanilla interpreter you can add various
expert system like features:

- Knowledge Acquisition
- Explanations
- Certainty Factors
- Forward Chaining
- Frame Representations
- Etc...

Bye

P.S.: The following book shows how:
http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/