# Prolog: "Vanilla" metainterpreter with builtins

Tags: prolog, prolog-metainterpreter

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165685/how-to-create-meta-rules-and-or-meta-interpreter-for-an-expert-system-with-swi-p/4176824#4176824) by Jan Burse shows one of the simplest implementations of a metainterpreter in Prolog:

```
solve(true) :- !.
solve((A,B)) :- !, solve(A), solve(B).
solve(H) :- clause(H,B), solve(B).
```

I would like to extend this interpreter so that it can call builtins. The vanilla one isn't able to handle calls such as `solve(member(X, [1,2,3,4]))`. Is this possible using ISO predicates? If not, is it possible using SWI-Prolog predicates?

Comment: In some Prolog systems, the more ISO compatible ones, you need to mark the predicates dynamic, so that clause/2 can find them. This is SWI-Prolog specific that it returns also static predicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow is refusing to accept my answer :) that was

Just call/1 them

*Edit*

For instance

```
?- [user].
solve(true) :- !.
|: solve((A,B)) :- !, solve(A), solve(B).
|: solve(H) :- clause(H,B), solve(B).
|: solve(T) :- call(T).
|: ^Dtrue.

?- solve(member(X, [1,2,3,4])).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4.
```

The only addition: `solve(T) :- call(T)`.

Comment: This solution leaves a choice point, and then calls predicates twice. I now get: ?- solve(pet(X)).
X = cat ;
X = cat ;
X = cat ;
X = cat ;
X = cat ;
false. Instead only ?- solve(pet(X)).
X = cat ;
false.

Answer (score 3):

I think [**`predicate_property/2`**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=predicate_property/2) may be useful for your task.

As the name already implies, this predicate relates a predicate (head) to one ore more *properties*.

For example:

```
?- predicate_property((A,B), P).
P = interpreted ;
P = visible ;
P = built_in ;
P = static ;
P = imported_from(system) ;
etc.
```

From such properties, you can deduce whether a predicate is *built-in*, and the call it directly.

It is also available in [SICStus](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus//docs/latest/html/sicstus/mpg_002dref_002dpredicate_005fproperty.html).

Beware though: Not all built-in predicates retain their semantics when called directly. I think discussing what they are and how to interpret them would be well worth its own question.